# Fresh installation of debian and raid10 array with SSD and HDD

Tags: linux, raid, ssd

I have one 120Gb SDD and four 2Tb HDD at disposal. I would like to install Debian Squeeze on the SSD and create a software RAID10 array with the four HDD.
According to your experience, how to "distribute" the different areas (boot, home, swap, etc) on the five disks ?

- is only one ssd useful or shall I envisage two ssd in RAID1 ?
- the Debian updates grow up the SSD: in spite of that, is it a good idea to use this kind of disks ?

You should note that my experience is very limited ... I will appreciate simple answers and/or tutorials addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Put `/` on the ssd, and use the raid10 for bulk storage.  i.e. put `~/Videos` on it.

And yes, if you want to spend the extra money on it, a second ssd raided with the first would provide more speed and/or redundancy, though the one should be plenty fast enough.

Comment: put / on the ssd: what does it mean for you ?

Comment: @user62025, it means put the root directory on the ssd?

Comment: As you guess I am beginner with Linux. When you answer / means root, I understand that /var, /tmp will be on the SSD. It's probably wrong because these directories shall not be on a SSD according to the SSD documentation.
Could you clarify ?

Comment: @user62025, what documentation?  They can be on the SSD just fine.  What do you think people do who only have one drive, and it's an SSD?

Comment: Sorry my sentence isn't correctly formulated. I mean in this technology, people say the more we write the less the life of the ssd is. Therefore I tried to ask which directories I must exclude of the SSD.

Comment: You can mount a tmpfs for `/tmp` if you have a reasonable amount of RAM.

Comment: Also, any proper SSD will do wear leveling. Each cell may support only a limited (but still large) number of writes, but the whole drive will allow a *very* large number of small writes. Basically, *if you have a decent quality modern SSD and a normal workload, don't worry about write cycles*. If you're worried, just get a second one and run them in a RAID 1 (mirroring) configuration; the odds that they will fail at the same time are essentially nonexistent, and the odds that they will fail for the same virtual blocks at the same time are practically less than zero.